# display in a textView a .log file from a filePath

Tags: ios, swift, logging, swiftybeaver

I'm trying to display a .log file in a textview but can't seem to access the filepath properly. When I do it returns nil.  I'm using a pod called "SwiftyBeaver" to do the logging.  This is what the fileURL looks like:

> file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5C92E3E6-9E45-4869-9142-AB9E70EE4FCC/Library/Caches/swiftybeaver.log

This is the function I'm using to turn the .log into a string so I can display it in a textView

> ```
> private func loadTextWithFileName(_ fileName: String) -> String? {
>     guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: "log"),
>         let contents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path) else {return nil}
>     return contents
> }
> ```

This is how I'm displaying the text to the textView

> self.loggingTextView.text =
>   self.loadTextWithFileName(self.file.logFileURL!.absoluteString)

Comment: because of you put the full URL of the log file (not file name) to your function. I think you should change tie loadTextWithFileName function to loadTextFromPath

Answer (score 0):

The method that you are using `Bundle.main.path()` is mainly to search for files in your Bundle.

But it seems your `log` file is going to be in your Cache directory.

Here is how you can look for a file in your Cache directory of your app

```
private func loadTextWithFileName(_ fileName: String) -> String? {
        if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            let fileURL = dir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
            guard let text = try? String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8) else {
                return nil
            }
            return text
        }
        return nil
    }
```

You can add a `catch` block to your `try` case to check what the error is, in case you don't get the log file details.